# how to apply a function on a data set?

Tags: r, function, apply

I have the following  data set. When I run the following function it only produce one line of results. I need to find the Gomp for each tree.

```
Tree        a       b       k
4382        21,88   9,59    0,0538
4383        13,93   12,94   0,0811
4384        19,69   9,78    0,0597
4385        20,02   8,23    0,0489
4386        11,07   23,2    0,1276
4387        18,35   13,29   0,0772
4388        19,72   17,53   0,0961
4389        26,3    5,26    0,0278

DOY = c(1:365)

Gomp <- data.frame(DF$a * exp (-exp(DF$b-DF$k*DOY)))
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i need to find the Gomp for each tree

Comment: why is DOY 1 to 365, when ur df has only 8 records?

Comment: a, b and k are fixed parameters and DOY are days of year. i need to find for each tree the daily values besed on its own fixed values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm at least not quite sure whether I understood correct. Maybe a better question could improve the answers...

```
DF <- data.frame(Tree = c(4382, 4383, 4384, 5385, 4386), a = c(21.88, 13.93, 19.69, 20.02, 11.07), b = c(9.59, 12.95, 9.78, 8.23, 23.20), k = c(0.0538, 0.0811, 0.0597, 0.0489, 0.1276))
DOY <- c(1:365)
DF_new <-  data.frame(sapply(1:length(DF$Tree), function(x)(DF$a[x]*exp(-exp(DF$b[x]-DF$k[x]*DOY)))))
colnames(DF_new) <- DF$Tree
```

With sapply (apply, vapply,etc.) you can loop through vectors, lists, dataframe and so on. Without `1:length(DF$Tree)` the values are used instead of the index.